# Definite integral involving exponential, powers and trigonometric functions $\int_{-\pi}^\pi \exp (-qx^{ak}(x^2+d^2+2 \, dx \cos t)^{-a/2}) dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

Is it possible to evaluate the following integral?

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \exp \left({-qx^{ak}(x^2+d^2+2 \, dx \cos t)^{-a/2}} \right) dt$$

I am not able to find any related formula. Note that this integral follows from the expected value of $$\exp \left({-qx^{ak}(x^2+d^2+2 \, dx \cos t)^{-a/2}} \right)$$ over the uniform circular angle t in $[-\pi,\pi] $with PDF $f(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}$. Perhaps there is an indirect way to get this integral as well.

Best regards

Comment: I changed $\cos[t]$ to $\cos t$. If there was really supposed to be a floor function (which I doubt) someone can always change it back

Comment: @You'reInMyEye    Editing so many old questions over such a short period of time is not cool. It pushes new questions off the front page.

Comment: @user232456, unless it's not allowed by the rules, I don't feel like I did anything wrong. Bad question titles promote duplicates. I'm not fine with so many duplicates getting answered and upvoted. The faster I correct old questions, the better is Math.SE, since people can actually know what the question is about when searching

Comment: @You'reInMyEye Editing to improve the questions and their titles is good. Many thanks for doing that. But user232456 raises a valid point. Since every edit bumps the question on the front page, a streak of edits shortly after each other pushes new questions off the front page, and that is considered undesirable. If you could split your editing into smaller batches so that your edits don't make up a large share of the front page, that would be great.